# Get last number from a loop to reference it as an index in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to retrieve the last element in an array from $max and reference it in the array $set_of_path. I want only the last value. The problem with this code is this $max value who prints value 0 to end of file, thus instead of output the last value .. every element is implemented.. Can someone help me please. thanks in advance.

```
for($ind=0;$ind <count($array_file[0]['pair']);$ind++) {
    ....
    ...
if((($city)===$initial or ($city[0]===$initial))){

                    $x =$array_file[0]['pair'][$ind]['city'];//display all cities
                    if ((end($x))===$final){ 

                        //push $array_file content into the array
                        $xd[]=$array_file[0]['pair'][$ind];
                        $count=count(end($xd));

                            $last_element = array();
                            $a[] = array_merge($xd);
                            $end = count(end($a));
                            $push = array_push($last_element,$end);

                            $max = max($last_element)-1;
                            print_r($max);

                            $set_of_path=@$a[$max];
                            print_r($set_of_path);  

                            print_r('<pre>');
                    }

                    };
...
...
.
...
.
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SizeOf` for getting the count of the items in an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php

Solution

```
<?php

$i = 0;

//Process array in loop
//increment $i++; or $i = sizeof($array);

?>
```

Comment: i tried Sizeof but each time the loop is incremented, the value is updated and output 1 2 3 4... after the loop break.. so, size of is not efficient :/

Comment: Create a variable outside the loop and inside the loop just increment the number or just do sizeof through each iteration to update the variable outside the loop.